# Powershell module for SCCM Client

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

Is there a powershell module that I can uses on client system where I have the agents installed ?

I pushed the patches from SCCM Console to client with deployment status as "available" and need to run the install command from the machine where I have sccm agent installed. how can i do that ?

Comment: No, the SCCM Agent doesn't come with a client-side PowerShell module. If you want to push patches for immediate deployment you need to mark the deployment `Required` and not `Available`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, Is there any other method I can call sccm agent on the client to install the patches ?

Comment: Not that I know off - but that would also sort of defeat the whole purpose of deploying via SCCM in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can automate using the ClientSDK WMI classes and powershell.  There is a good writeup about it here

https://timmyit.com/2016/08/01/sccm-and-powershell-force-install-of-software-updates-thats-available-on-client-through-wmi/

https://byteben.com/bb/identifying-and-installing-sccm-client-software-updates-remotely-with-powershell-and-trigger-a-vmware-snapshot-before-remediation-part-1-of-3/

Answer (score 0):

It is better to just run a "Required" deployment on collection with the specific clients to want. [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/deploy-applications)

You may create that collection with query "where Client0 is 1" or doing fine-grain selection with direct membership. [Here's how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/clients/manage/collections/create-collections).

This way the SCCM Agent will be controlling the installation the whole way, and allow to:

- Handle temporarily offline clients
- Active users on the device
- Scheduling and windowing

and more...